# windows xp not booting up! help!

Tags: windows, boot

i just used roxo to system restore my laptop from its first saved state. now it won't boot up. it just says. "bootmgr compressed"

what do i do with this.

FYI my laptop is an HP Mini which do not have a cd rom. so Booting up windows XP from cd to fix it won't help me..

Please Help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this [XP Emergency Boot Loader on USB Flash Drive](http://www.technologyquestions.com/technology/windows-xp/380658-xp-emergency-boot-loader-usb-flash-drive.html)?

Answer (score -1):

Get to the command prompt screen and type **bootrec /fixboot**.

Then type **bootrec /fixmbr**.

Comment: That's 1) for Vista and above, 2) a little hard to do when the OS won't boot.